# How to change vuetify datepicker accepting date format

Tags: vue.js, nuxt.js, vuetify.js

I receive a date from an API and it is a string like this

```
2021-11-18T12:57:22.177
```

I have **v-modeled** this with Vuetify date picker

```html
<v-menu
  v-model="date_picker"
  :close-on-content-click="false"
  :nudge-right="40"
  transition="scale-transition"
  offset-y
  min-width="auto"
>
  <template v-slot:activator="{ on, attrs }">
    <!-- v-validate="{ required: r.count > 0 }"
  :error-messages="errors.collect(r.title)" -->
    <v-text-field
      :name="s.title"
      :value="converDate(s.expierDate)"
      label="expierDate"
      dense
      prepend-icon="mdi-calendar"
      readonly
      v-bind="attrs"
      v-on="on"
    ></v-text-field>
  </template>
  <v-date-picker
    v-model="s.expierDate"
    @input="date_picker = false"
  ></v-date-picker>
</v-menu>
```

However, date picker doesn't accept this format. What can I do?

Answer (score 1):

Add a `computed` to return an ISO string of your date and only the first `10` characters, so you end up with `2021-11-18` like this:

```js
computed: {
  isoDate() {
    return new Date(this.s.expierDate).toISOString().substr(0,10);
  }
}
```

(Side note you spelled `expire` wrong.)

Also double side note in that from your code snippet it's not clear what `s.expierDate` is so the computed above probably won't work without some minor tweaking but the logic still applies.

Then in your template `v-model="isoDate"`.

Here is a generic example I quickly threw together (view in "Full page" so doesn't look weird):

```js
new Vue({
  el: '#app',
  vuetify: new Vuetify(),
  data () {
    return {
      picker: new Date('1989-07-28').toISOString().substr(0, 10),
    };
  },
})
```

```html
<script src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/vue@2.x/dist/vue.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/vuetify@2.x/dist/vuetify.js"></script><link href="https://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Roboto:100,300,400,500,700,900" rel="stylesheet">
<link href="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/@mdi/font@4.x/css/materialdesignicons.min.css" rel="stylesheet">
<link href="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/vuetify@2.x/dist/vuetify.min.css" rel="stylesheet">

<div id="app">
  <v-app id="inspire">
    <v-row justify="center">
      <v-date-picker v-model="picker"></v-date-picker>
    </v-row>
  </v-app>
</div>
```

[Here is a fiddle](https://codepen.io/maxshuty/pen/RwZOpRg?editors=101) if you want to play around

Comment: it work like this ,BUT will not when you use datepicker like a dropdpon menu

Comment: @kevin not sure why you're talking about a dropdown menu here. There is nothing related to this in your question.